# Connect flex cable to raspberry

Tags: display, cable

I have an old tablet `Galaxy Tab GT-P1000` and I would like to ask if it could be possible to connect to raspberry? Size of flex cable looks similar...

[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07V4GWYRN)

Comment: That is a display cable for that particular tablet. I highly doubt you can use it for anything else. Of course, you should be able to connect that tablet using Wifi or USB to the Pi.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, I will try USB

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can. Not wirelessly always. It is a mobile device with its own operating system. Unless you can install RealVNC on that from a software store. If you can, you can also install RealVNC on Raspbian and connect it to your tablet wirelessly.